# Some users cannot see image file on public

Tags: image-display

I have a migration project and where web part used has good html code to reference an image on the fileserver that within our domain everyone has read only access to.

A few testers cannot render this image and one is our new sys admin for the company.  Rights issue is out of the question with her.

What other things can I check to make all of these images render?

This is section for file:
src="file:\Server\public\intranetimages\Confronting_Unsafe_Behavior.jpg"

Most of my users see this in test but I need 100% hit ratio.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is image file published?

Comment: 90% of testers can see this page properly.  Only a few cannot.  The image is outside of sharepoint and a part of a video users can see on plant safety.

Comment: have you asked user to access that image path directly and check if they can see and open this image or not.

Comment: Sorry yes she can click on the link if placed in her explorer and the image displays.  That was a \\<Server>\<path>\file_name.jpg

Comment: Am trying this tweak of web config:

Comment: https://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/sharepoint-2013-after-upgrade-images-are-not-rendering/

Comment: Is they are using IE? Chrome, Firefox and most of the other browsers does not allow opening shared/network folder files due to security reasons.

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/224500/how-to-display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol

Comment: The file is inside an image tag src="file:\\Server\Path\Name.jpg"  that should work when it Is a file on the domain the SharePoint is running off of.

Comment: It was browser settings for the few users.